# .htaccess double rewrite rule to the same file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making an app where you can store files in folders and so on.

I have a little problem in my .htaccess file cause I want to be able to redirect two rules to the same page, one with a attribute on without.

I want `example.com/drive` to reqrite itself to `example.com/drive.php` and it does so this part works, but I also want `example.com/drive/path/to/a/dir/here/` to rewrite itself to `example.com/drive?dir=drive/path/to/a/dir/here/` .

Is this possible with a .htaccess file? And if it is, how?

This is the code I got so far:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /err/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /err/500.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$ /profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^f/(.+)$ /file.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^s/(.+)/(.+)$ /page.php?p=$1&f=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^s/(.+)$ /page.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dir/(.+)$ /drive.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This code works by using dir not drive in the url, but that is not what I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think why it's works by using *dir* and not by *drive*? And are all the folders on *example.com/drive/path/to/a/dir/here/*, variables? Means, they're dynamically change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules would be correct (if you change `dir` to `drive` as mentioned), you just need to reorder them a little:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /err/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /err/500.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# first handle these explicit pattern matches
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$         /profile.php?u=$1   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^f/(.+)$         /file.php?f=$1      [L,QSA]
# it's quite likely this is what you want here instead:
RewriteRule ^s/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /page.php?p=$1&f=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^s/(.+)$         /page.php?p=$1      [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^drive/(.+)$     /drive.php?dir=$1   [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# I'm guessing you want to only rewrite to script that exists in the root, if
# this is not the case you can change this back to .+
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ /$0.php [L,QSA]
```